# NavigableSet can't add different sub class

Tags: java, collections

I have a NavigableSet and want to add two element into it, but got cast failure ,how to fix it? AModel and BModel both implement BaseModel

```
 BaseModel AModel = new AModel();

 BaseModel BModel = new BModel();

 NavigableSet<BaseModel > ns = new TreeSet<BaseModel>(Arrays.asList(AModel, BModel));
```

Exception:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.simon.main.AModel cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeSet.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.simon.main.Test3.main(Test3.java:18)
```

BaseModel

```
 public interface BaseModel {

  }
```

AModel

```
 public class AModel implements BaseModel{

  }
```

BModel

```
 public class BModel implements BaseModel{

  }
```

Comment: Sidenote: as per Java coding conventions (which you should stick to in order to make it easier to help you) the variable names should be `aModel` instead of `AModel` etc.

Comment: Another note: can you post the stacktrace of the exception? My answer was not correct since I missed the variables being both of type `BaseModel` (your style got me) and thus `Arrays.asList()` should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not passing in a `Comparator` to the `TreeSet` constructor, then your elements *must* implement `Comparable` (and must be comparable to each other's type).  None of your types are `Comparable`.

Read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet(java.util.Collection)) for the constructor you're using:

> All elements inserted into the set must implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all such elements must be mutually comparable: e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the set.